# Replace Id of one column by a name from another table while using the count statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I am trying to get the count of patients by province for my school project, I have managed to get the count and the Id of the province in a table but since I am using the count statement it will not let me use join to show the ProvinceName instead of the Id (it says it's not numerical).

Here is the schema of the two tables I am talking about

[image: The two tables]

The content of the Province table is as follow:

| ProvinceId | ProvinceName | ProvinceShortName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Terre-Neuve-et-Labrador | NL |
| 2 | Île-du-Prince-Édouard | PE |
| 3 | Nouvelle-Écosse | NS |
| 4 | Nouveau-Brunswick | NB |
| 5 | Québec | QC |
| 6 | Ontario | ON |
| 7 | Manitoba | MB |
| 8 | Saskatchewan | SK |
| 9 | Alberta | AB |
| 10 | Colombie-Britannique | BC |
| 11 | Yukon | YT |
| 12 | Territoires du Nord-Ouest | NT |
| 13 | Nunavut | NU |

And here is n sample data from the Patient table (don't worry it's fake data!):

| SS | FirstName | LastName | InsuranceNumber | InsuranceProvince | DateOfBirth | Sex | PhoneNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Doris | Patel | PATD778276 | 5 | 1977-08-02 | F | 514-754-6488 |
| 3 | Judith | Doe | DOEJ7712917 | 5 | 1977-12-09 | F | 418-267-2263 |
| 4 | Rosemary | Barrett | BARR05122566 | 6 | 2005-12-25 | F | 905-638-5062 |
| 5 | Cody | Kennedy | KENC047167 | 10 | 2004-07-01 | M | 604-833-7712 |

I managed to get the patient count by province using the following statement:

```
select count(SS),InsuranceProvince
from Patient
full JOIN Province ON Patient.InsuranceProvince = Province.ProvinceId    
group by InsuranceProvince
```

which gives me the following table:

| PatientCount | InsuranceProvince |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | 1 |
| 33 | 2 |
| 54 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 608 | 5 |
| 1778 | 6 |
| 25 | 7 |
| 209 | 8 |
| 547 | 9 |
| 649 | 10 |
| 6 | 11 |
| 35 | 12 |
| 24 | 13 |

How can I replace the id's with the correct ProvinceShortName to get the following final result?

| ProvinceName | PatientCount |
| --- | --- |
| NL | 13 |
| PE | 33 |
| NS | 54 |
| NB | 4 |
| QC | 608 |
| ON | 1778 |
| MB | 25 |
| SK | 209 |
| AB | 547 |
| BC | 649 |
| YT | 6 |
| NT | 35 |
| NU | 24 |

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: You might want to ponder a bit on the aspect of *minimal* in [example]...

Comment: Not using images is nothing to do with being devs or not, it just makes the site work a whole lot better without them, and from your perspective allows people to copy and paste your data out to help answer your question - is that enough self interest? :)

Comment: Thanks guys i will read and try to get better at following the rules, i promise !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can actually just specify that in the select. Note that it's best practise to include the thing you group by in the select, but since your question is so specific then...

```
SELECT ProvinceShortName, COUNT(SS) AS PatientsInProvince
FROM Patient
    JOIN Province ON Patient.InsuranceProvince=Province.ProvinceId
GROUP BY InsuranceProvince;
```

Comment: When trying your answer i get the following error: Column 'Province.ProvinceShortName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause., Any idea ?

Comment: In SQL Server (and any other decent DBMS) you need to include it in `GROUP BY`, like this: `GROUP BY InsuranceProvince, ProvinceShortName`.

Comment: Thank you @Vladimir Baranov it works perfectly now !

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest:

```
select pr.ProvinceShortName, count(*)
from Patient p join
     Province pr
     on p.InsuranceProvince = pr.ProvinceId    
group by pr.ProvinceShortName
order by min(pr.ProvinceId);
```

Notes:

- The key is including the columns you want in the `select` and `group by`.
- You seem to want the results in province number order, so I included an `order by`.
- There is no need to count the non-NULL values of `SS`.  You might as well use `count(*)`.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you need to show the patient count by province.

```
SELECT 
  Province.ProvinceShortName AS [ProvinceName]
 ,COUNT(1) as [PatinetCount] 
FROM Patient
  RIGHT JOIN Province ON Patient.InsuranceProvince = Province.ProvinceId    
GROUP BY  ProvinceShortName
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Just altering your query to

```
select ProvinceShortName As PatientCount,count(InsuranceProvince) As PatientCount
from Patient
full JOIN Province ON Patient.InsuranceProvince = Province.ProvinceId    
group by ProvinceShortName
```